# How to console log big object in nodejs 11

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js 11 when I `console.log` big object it throws stack trace error, or logs full object with all inheritance.

I `console.log` dom object in jest test and receive error below, if I log small object all works fine.

[image: error]

Comment: If you want to check a large object, I think you should print obejct content to a text file, or using a debugger tool.

Comment: You could also look into converting your object to something that be streamed and then piping that stream to `process.stdout`

Answer (score 0):

This tends to occur based on two cases,

1) When you have a limited memory set in your `Node.js` and when and execution requires more than that.

==> In situations like this, you can try increasing your memory limit like this (the following allocates 4GB memory) ,

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 YOUR_SCRIPT.js
```

2) When your `console.log` tries to output a variable where it is getting manipulated asynchronously.

==> In situations like this, you can opt for this good library called [console-sync](https://github.com/litmit/console-sync) which patches the traditional `console.log` and outputs the variable synchronously.

Hope this helps!